# Show multiple boxes with mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to show this kind of box when user click "Add another" button. If he clicks again, I just want to show another box( maximum 3 boxes) if he exceed that amount(3 boxes), need to "add another" button to be disabled.

[image]

Currently it's showing only one box by one mouse click. I tried using data target attribute like this and it's working fine but it show one box only.

**Snippet Code**

```js
$(".add-box").click(function() {
  $(".add-box-wrap" + $(this).data('target')).show(); //.add-box-wrap1 or .add-box-wrap2 
});

$(".claim-btn-close").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
.add-box-wrap1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.claim-btn-close {
  top: -7px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 34px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #e46a5d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #e46a5d;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-box-wrap1" style="display: none;">
  <div class="claim-btn-close">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="btn claim-btn">Claim 1</a>
</div>

<div class="add-box-wrap2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="claim-btn-close">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="btn claim-btn">Claim 2</a>
</div>

<div class="form-group add-form">
  <label for="" class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="add-btn">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <a class="add-box" data-target="1">Add another&ensp;<i class="fa fa-plus">
       </i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I posted example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/36kbhkgk/1/) It might be causing data attribute? Because "add another" button has data-target="1" so it's showing associate with add-box-wrap1 box only. So what is the best solution for showing 3 boxes one by one?

Comment: Can't you have 3 `add-box-wrap-*` boxes and show them 1 by 1 on click ?

Comment: Let me check,,,

Answer (score 1):

Just give a common class name for both of the boxes and select them by their class name and hide/show them. I have slightly modified your code. Hope this will work for you.

HTML

```js
$(".add-box").click(function() {
  $(".claim-box").show();
});

$(".claim-btn-close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
.claim-btn-close{
  top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -14px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #e46a5d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #e46a5d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-box-wrap1{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-box-wrap1 claim-box" style="display: none;">
 <div class="claim-btn-close">
 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<a href="" class="btn claim-btn">Claim 1</a>
</div>

<div class="add-box-wrap2 claim-box" style="display: none;">
  <div class="claim-btn-close">
   <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="btn claim-btn">Claim 2</a>
</div>

<div class="form-group add-form">
 <label for="" class="control-label"></label>
 <div class="add-btn">
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <a class="add-box" data-target="1">Add another&ensp;<i class="fa fa-plus">
   </i></a>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a clone of your code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c25bd56d/2/)

```
 $(".add-box").click(function() {

  //$(".add-box-wrap").show(); //.add-box-wrap1 or .add-box-wrap2 
  if ($(".add-box-wrap").length < 4) {
  var box = $($(".add-box-wrap")[0]).clone().show();
  box.appendTo($(".container"));
    }
});

$(".claim-btn-close").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

1. move your box outside the main container as a template
2. clone box until count for boxes are not more then 3(including template)

Comment: This seems fine but it showing claim 1 three times. The second one should be claim 2

Comment: I showed you concept, I guess you can change text yourself

Answer (score 1):

In that case, change your `$('.add-box').click` function to this

```
$(".add-box").click(function() {
    if($(".add-box-wrap" + $(this).data('target')).is(":visible")) {
    $(".add-box-wrap" + ($(this).data('target')+1)).show();
    $(this).data('target', ($(this).data('target')+2));
  } else {
    $(".add-box-wrap" + $(this).data('target')).show();
  }
});
```

In this change, you are checking whether the "clicked" data-attribute's corresponding `.add-box-wrap` is visible or not. If visible then add `1` to the `data-target` and show that next one. After showing finally add `2`(so on next click you can directly show the 3rd button)

Your [Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/36kbhkgk/12/)

Comment: This works fine! But one thing I notice that, when you close all three boxes and click again "add another" it will give you "claim 3"

Comment: Right, that could be fixed. First tell me if you close only 2nd box and then click "add another", what should happen ?

Comment: You mean it should "automatically dynamically" change?

Comment: @CssSY - I'm actually asking mate ... I'm not being sarcastic :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149984/discussion-between-csssy-and-nikhil-nanjappa).